# Why doesn't the setenv and tftp command work in my UBoot boot.scr script?

Tags: bootloader, u-boot

The following UBoot commands when entered manually via the UBoot prompt successfully load an image from my TFTP server:

```
setenv ipaddr 192.168.0.199
setenv serverip 192.168.0.198
tftp 0x10000000 rpi3bp/image.bin
go 0x10000000
```

However, when I compile a `boot.scr` file with the `mkimage` Uboot utility containing the above commands like so:

```
echo ===== Saving RPi's IP Address =====
setenv ipaddr 192.168.0.199

echo ===== Saving Home TFTP server's IP Address =====
setenv serverip 192.168.0.198

echo ===== Loading file from Home TFTP server =====
tftp 0x10000000 rpi3bp/image.bin

echo ===== Running image =====
go 0x10000000
```

I get the following failed output when my device boots using this `boot.scr` script:

```
...
Found U-Boot script /boot.scr
359 bytes read in 2 ms (174.8 KiB/s)
## Executing script at 02400000
===== Saving RPis IP Address =====
setenv ipaddr 192.168.0.199

echo ===== Saving Home TFTP servers IP Address =====
===== Loading file from Home TFTP server =====
lan78xx_eth Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete........ done
*** ERROR: `ipaddr' not set
===== Running image =====
## Starting application at 0x10000000 ...
"Synchronous Abort" handler, esr 0x02000000
elr: ffffffffd4d27000 lr : 0000000000088cc0 (reloc)
elr: 0000000010000000 lr : 000000003b361cc0
x0 : 0000000000000001 x1 : 000000003af6a028
x2 : 000000003af6a028 x3 : 000000000000003f
x4 : 000000003af60df0 x5 : 0000000000000000
x6 : 0000000000000000 x7 : 0000000000c0c0c0
x8 : 0000000000000010 x9 : 0000000000000008
x10: 00000000ffffffd0 x11: 0000000000000010
x12: 0000000000000000 x13: 0000000000000200
x14: 000000003b3cc640 x15: 0000000000000001
x16: 0000000010000000 x17: 0fac920a292163a0
x18: 000000003af54db0 x19: 000000003af6a028
x20: 0000000010000000 x21: 0000000000000002
x22: 000000003af6a020 x23: 0000000000000002
x24: 000000003b3e567c x25: 0000000000000000
x26: 0000000000000000 x27: 0000000000000000
x28: 000000003af6a080 x29: 000000003af52ed0

Code: aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa a2aaaaaa (55555555)
```

Seems like `ipaddr` isn't getting saved and the TFTP file isn't getting copied from the server but I'm not sure why.

What am I doing wrong here in my UBoot script and how can I fix it?

Should `boot.scr` work just as one would be entering UBoot commands manually in the UBoot prompt?

Edit 1:

I've just hexdumped my `boot.scr` binary and can confirm I have Unix line endings and not Windows line endings, which is consistent with the fact that I'm using MacOS.

```
❯ hexdump -C boot.scr
00000000  27 05 19 56 fc 01 13 df  63 d4 67 63 00 00 01 27  |'..V�..�c�gc...'|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  a6 de 91 ea 05 02 06 01  |........��.�....|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000040  00 00 01 1f 00 00 00 00  0a 65 63 68 6f 20 3d 3d  |.........echo ==|
00000050  3d 3d 3d 20 53 61 76 69  6e 67 20 52 50 69 27 73  |=== Saving RPi's|
00000060  20 49 50 20 41 64 64 72  65 73 73 20 3d 3d 3d 3d  | IP Address ====|
00000070  3d 0a 73 65 74 65 6e 76  20 69 70 61 64 64 72 20  |=.setenv ipaddr |
00000080  31 39 32 2e 31 36 38 2e  30 2e 31 39 39 0a 0a 65  |192.168.0.199..e|
00000090  63 68 6f 20 3d 3d 3d 3d  3d 20 53 61 76 69 6e 67  |cho ===== Saving|
000000a0  20 48 6f 6d 65 20 54 46  54 50 20 73 65 72 76 65  | Home TFTP serve|
000000b0  72 27 73 20 49 50 20 41  64 64 72 65 73 73 20 3d  |r's IP Address =|
000000c0  3d 3d 3d 3d 0a 73 65 74  65 6e 76 20 73 65 72 76  |====.setenv serv|
000000d0  65 72 69 70 20 31 39 32  2e 31 36 38 2e 30 2e 31  |erip 192.168.0.1|
000000e0  39 38 0a 0a 65 63 68 6f  20 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 20 4c  |98..echo ===== L|
000000f0  6f 61 64 69 6e 67 20 66  69 6c 65 20 66 72 6f 6d  |oading file from|
00000100  20 48 6f 6d 65 20 54 46  54 50 20 73 65 72 76 65  | Home TFTP serve|
00000110  72 20 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 0a  74 66 74 70 20 30 78 31  |r =====.tftp 0x1|
00000120  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 20  72 70 69 33 62 70 2f 69  |0000000 rpi3bp/i|
00000130  6d 61 67 65 2e 62 69 6e  0a 0a 65 63 68 6f 20 3d  |mage.bin..echo =|
00000140  3d 3d 3d 3d 20 52 75 6e  6e 69 6e 67 20 69 6d 61  |==== Running ima|
00000150  67 65 20 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d  0a 67 6f 20 30 78 31 30  |ge =====.go 0x10|
00000160  30 30 30 30 30 30 0a                              |000000.|
00000167
```

Comment: Before the **tftp** operation, do a sanity check by issuing a **printenv** command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the single quote (') which marks the start of a string:

`echo ===== Saving RPi's IP Address =====`

Please, remove the single quotes

`echo ===== Saving RPis IP Address =====`

The return value of the tfpt command should be checked. You don' want to jump to an address where nothing has been loaded.

```
echo ===== Saving RPis IP Address =====
setenv ipaddr 192.168.0.199

echo ===== Saving Home TFTP servers IP Address =====
setenv serverip 192.168.0.198

echo ===== Loading file from Home TFTP server =====
tftp 0x10000000 rpi3bp/image.bin; setenv ret $?

echo ===== Running image =====
if test $ret -eq 0; then go 0x10000000; fi
```

Comment: Strange - I've just hexdumped my `boot.scr` file and as you can see, I have UNIX line endings. Is there anything else funny with my `boot.scr` file?